How to deal with PrismaClientValidationError?
I'm writing logout and refresh tokens function using nestjs, prisma, jwt. But I'm running into Invalid this.prisma.user.updateMany() invocation. here's a detailed error.
logout function error:
Invalid `this.prisma.user.updateMany()` invocation in
...auth.service.ts:45:32
  42 }
  43
  44 async logout(userId: number) {
→ 45     await this.prisma.user.updateMany({
           where: {
             id: {
               sub: 5,
               ~~~
               email: "dummymail",
               iat: 1713191159,
               exp: 1713192059,
         ?     equals?: Int | IntFieldRefInput,
         ?     in?: Int[],
         ?     notIn?: Int[],
         ?     lt?: Int | IntFieldRefInput,
         ?     lte?: Int | IntFieldRefInput,
         ?     gt?: Int | IntFieldRefInput,
         ?     gte?: Int | IntFieldRefInput,
         ?     not?: Int | NestedIntFilter
             },
             hashedRt: {
               not: null
             }
           },
           data: {
             hashedRt: null
           }
         })

Unknown argument `sub`. Did you mean `in`? Available options are marked with ?.
PrismaClientValidationError:

refreshtoken function error:
Invalid `this.prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation in
auth.service.ts:60:45

  57 }
  58
  59 async refreshTokens(userId: number, rt: string) {
→ 60     const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
           where: {
             id: {
               sub: 5,
               email: "admin@gmail.com",
               iat: 1713191159,
               exp: 1713795959,
               refreshToken: "token is here"
             }
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           }
         })

Argument `id`: Invalid value provided. Expected Int, provided Object.
PrismaClientValidationError:

and here is the auth.service.ts source code:
import { ForbiddenException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { AuthDto } from './dto/auth.dto';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Tokens } from './types';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService,
    private jwtService: JwtService){}

    async signupLocal(dto: AuthDto): Promise<Tokens> {
        const hash = await this.hashData(dto.password);

        const newUser = await this.prisma.user.create({
           data:{
                email: dto.email,
                hash,
            },
        });
        const tokens = await this.getTokens(newUser.id, newUser.email);
        await this.updateRtHash(newUser.id, tokens.refresh_token);
        return tokens;
    }

    async signinLocal(dto:AuthDto): Promise<Tokens> {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
            where:{
                email: dto.email,
            },
        });

        if (!user) throw new ForbiddenException("Oruulkue");

        const passwordMatches = await bcrypt.compare(dto.password, user.hash);
        if (!passwordMatches) throw new ForbiddenException("Oruulkue");

        const tokens = await this.getTokens(user.id, user.email);
        await this.updateRtHash(user.id, tokens.refresh_token);
        return tokens;
    }

    async logout(userId: number) {
        await this.prisma.user.updateMany({
            where:{
                id:userId, 
                hashedRt: {
                    not: null,
                }
            },
            data: {
                hashedRt: null,
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    
    async refreshTokens(userId: number, rt: string) {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({//
            where: {
                id: userId,
            },
        });
        if(!user || !user.hashedRt) throw new ForbiddenException("Oruulkue")
        
        const rtMatches = await bcrypt.compare(rt, user.hashedRt)
        if(!rtMatches) throw new ForbiddenException("Oruulkue")

        const tokens = await this.getTokens(user.id, user.email);
        await this.updateRtHash(user.id, tokens.refresh_token);
        return tokens;
    }

    async updateRtHash(userId: number, rt: string){
        const hash = await this.hashData(rt)
        await this.prisma.user.update({
            where: {
                id: userId,
            },
            data: {
                hashedRt: hash,
            },
        });
    }

    hashData(data: string){
        return bcrypt.hash(data, 10);
    }

    async getTokens(userId: number, email: string){
        const [at, rt] = await Promise.all([
            this.jwtService.signAsync(
                {
                    sub: userId,
                    email,
                },
                {
                    secret: 'at-secret',
                    expiresIn: 60*15,
                },
            ),
            this.jwtService.signAsync(
                {
                    sub: userId,
                    email,
                },
                {
                    secret: 'rt-secret',
                    expiresIn: 60*60*24*7,
                },  
            ),
        ]);

        return{
            access_token: at,
            refresh_token: rt,
        };
    }

}


Does anyone have solved this error before?
Thank you.
If anyone has solved this error before please help me to deal with it. I'm new with the TypeScript. Thank you.

Your where clause is incorrect. It seems like you are trying to add the values into the filter. where expects a filter which identifies which rows to update and where: { id: { sub: 5 } } is invalid.
You should be doing something like:
async logout(userId: number) {
  await this.prisma.user.updateMany({
    // Your filter: which records to update
    where: {
      id: 5
    },
    // The data
    data: {
      email: "dummymail",
      iat: 1713191159,
      exp: 1713192059,
    },
  });
};


Look at Prisma's documentation to grasp how updateMany (and other statements, for that matter) work.
Is that sub meant to update records which have id value lower than 5? If yes, you should be using lt (lower than) or lte (lower than or equal to):
// ...
where: {
  id: {
    lt: 5
  },
},
data: { ... }

See documentation on filter conditions.

Hello thanks for your anwer. Explaining further: This function was working properly before I added some guards. But still I don't understand why I'm having this error. sub means that user id within the jwt token.

I don't know what those guards are, but your where filter is wrong: id should be an integer, but you are trying to filter by an object. Just like the error message says: "Argument id: Invalid value provided. Expected Int, provided Object." Fix your where filter like I suggested.
